# Добавление в слайс числа по [0] индексу

Tags: golang

Вопрос: как вставить в слайс по индексу `[0]` число, не затирая предыдущее значение в памяти (т.е  число 2 на единицу), которое там  хранится.

Решение есть: это 2 слайса смержить через `append`, но выделять память под слайс для вставки одного числа  это затратно и глупо.

```golang
var slice1 = []int{2, 3, 4} // создал слайс
var slice2 = make([]int, len(slice1), cap(slice1))   

// создал слайс точную копию slice1, но пустую
copy(slice2, slice1)       //скопировал
slice2 = append(slice2, 5) //добавил  число 5 в конец
slice2[0] = 1  // заменяет число  с 2-ки на 1  по индексу [0]- 
               // элемент первого слайса
sliceLength := len(slice2)
sliceCapacity := cap(slice2)
fmt.Println("Array :", slice2[:])
fmt.Println("Length :", sliceLength)
fmt.Println("Capacity :", sliceCapacity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно создать новый срез с нужным значением(и) и добавить нужные данные в конец вновь созданного, т.к. слайс это ссылка на основной массив, ничто никуда не копируется, создается новая ссылка на те же данные в одной и той же памяти, просто новый операнд, который не меняет исходные данные. если не ошибаюсь, вроде это эффективнее, чем копировать.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func main() {

var s = []int{2, 3, 4}
var one = []int{1}
one = append(one, s...)
fmt.Println(one)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Это же вектор. Либо [аллоцируйте новый и копируйте](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#push-frontunshift), либо добавляйте элемент в конец и переносите все элементы на единицу вправо:

```golang
var s = []int{2, 3, 4}
s = append(s, 0)
copy(s[1:], s)
s[0] = 1
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lWg2NeJwBt2.

Эти два варианта будут иметь разные характеристики быстродействия на разных платформах и при разных N, так что делайте приближённые к реальным данным [бенчмарки](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).